# Why is kafka connect distributed mode always assigned only one task?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have deployed kafka connect elasticsearch.

Connect distributed is running confluent 3.1.2.
(It was operated as one group.id in total 4 equipments.)

I've given `tasks.max=4`, but I do not know why I get only one task.

Comment: I changed "developed" to "deployed"... Not sure which you have done, but Confluent includes `kafka-connect-elasticsearch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka Connect in distributed mode will create sink tasks equal to the minimum of (a) tasks.max and (b) the total number of partitions to be exported.

How many topic/partitions are you trying to export to elasticsearch?

Comment: The number of partitions for that topic in the broker is 3,
When I run connector elasticsearch using curl POST, I set tasks.max to 4. (I also tried it with 3.)

Comment: And when I look at config.storage.topic as a console consumer, the string {"tasks": 1} appears.

Comment: When I run the connector, I will see the following output from the taskConfigs () method of the class that implements the connector interface:  
    [2018-05-03 11:16:59,671] INFO Setting task configurations for 1 workers.

Comment: override def taskConfigs(maxTasks: Int): util.List[util.Map[String, String]] = {
    logger.info("Setting task configurations for {} workers.", maxTasks.toString)

    (1 to maxTasks) map { _=> props.get }
  }